# create a new column based on special character anywhere in other column in R

Tags: r

I have a column (runscored) in dataframe =df It contains some number with * sign I need to create another column which mentions `" notout  "` if runscored has * sign else out.

```
df=
runscored
34
45
6
9
62*
55
70*
```

I want this:

```
runscored      out/notout
34              out
45              out
6               out
9*              notout
62*             notout
55              out
70*             notout
```

I have tried this code

`df$out/notout <- ifelse(grepl("*", df$Runs Scored, ignore.case = T), "notout","out")`

But new column with notout only

Comment: There are a couple of things to note in what you tried; when you are creating the variable out/notout R generally views / as the division operation, so to have it as part of a variable name you need to enclose the name in backticks `, * is a token that means 0 or more of the preceding character so to make it literal you need to escape it using two backslashes \\, and when using the dfRuns Scored, make sure you use the correct variable name with the same case as it is defined in your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix `*` with `\\` if you want to search string `*` otherwise it will always return `TRUE`.

```
df$`out/notout` <- with(df, ifelse(grepl("\\*", runscored), "notout", "out"))
```

**Output is:**

```
> df
  runscored out/notout
1        34        out
2        45        out
3         6        out
4         9        out
5       62*     notout
6        55        out
7       70*     notout
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(runscored = c("34", "45", "6", "9", "62*", "55", 
"70*"), `out/notout` = c("out", "out", "out", "out", "notout", 
"out", "notout")), .Names = c("runscored", "out/notout"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```